# Problem in Flutter. Conflict between Firebase previous and last version Authentication

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make login and Signup features for my project but stuck in converting from Firebase old version to the new latest one. As I want to check if user signed in or not, I have added currentUser() method but then I got an error. 
As I understand FirebaseUser class has replaced by AuthResult class
The main problem comes from currentUser() method: Error is the following and when I want to register, app shuts down;
(NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'uid' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: uid)

This the old:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

abstract class BaseAuth {
  Future<String> signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);
  Future<String> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);
  Future<String> currentUser();
  Future<void> signOut();
}

class Auth implements BaseAuth {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  Future<String> signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    return user?.uid;
  }

  @override
  Future<String> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    return user?.uid;
  }

  @override
  Future<String> currentUser() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    return user?.uid;
  }

  @override
  Future<void> signOut() async {
    return _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }
}
```

This is the new one:

```
abstract class BaseAuth{
  Future<String> signInWithEmailAndPassword (String email, String password);
  Future<String> createUserWithEmailAndPassword (String email, String password);
  Future<String> currentUser();

}

class Auth implements BaseAuth{


@override
  Future<String> signInWithEmailAndPassword (String email, String password) async {
    final AuthResult user = await FirebaseAuth.instance
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
            return user.user.uid;
  }
@override
  Future<String> createUserWithEmailAndPassword (String email, String password) async {
    final AuthResult user = await FirebaseAuth.instance
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
            return user.user.uid;
  }
@override
  Future<String> currentUser() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    return user.uid;  //Error comes from here
  }

@override
  Future<void> signOut() async {
    return _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }

}
```

Comment: wrap your method in a try catch and print out the error, it might be that the method throws an error and not returning any user. or you can just check if the user is not null

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The case here is that,   when even I check if the user  ( return user?.uid; ) is not null  app shuts down. Connection getting lost. Don't know why?